# Finding the Speed of each participant on SQL Table

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, performance, derivative

I have an SQL table on several people's movements (people_movement), like so:

| Name | Time | Position Increment (m) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brittany | 10.20 | -75 |
| Brittany | 10.30 | 800 |
| Brittany | 10.45 | 800 |
| Brittany | 11.00 | 900 |
| Alan | 10.15 | 400 |
| Alan | 10.16 | -700 |
| Alan | 1020 | 800 |
| Casey | 9.50 | 800 |
| Casey | 10.01 | -400 |
| Casey | 10.05 | 200 |

Notice that the time is recorded, so for the first record, the start time is unknown, but the time of a row is used as the start time of the next row.
There are thousands of participants with different number of rows, some of the participants has 4 or 5 rows, but many has 100s.
I Need to compute the speed of their movement (m/minutes), so the table will look like so:

| Name | Start Time | End Time | Position Increment (m) | Increment Speed (m/min) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brittany | - | 10.20 | -75 | - |
| Brittany | 10.20 | 10.30 | 800 | 80 |
| Brittany | 10.30 | 11.45 | 800 | 53.33 |
| Brittany | 10.45 | 11.00 | 900 | 60 |
| Alan | - | 10.15 | 400 | - |
| Alan | 10.15 | 10.16 | -700 | -700 |
| Alan | 10.16 | 10.20 | 800 | 200 |
| Casey | - | 09.50 | 800 | - |
| Casey | 09.50 | 10.01 | -400 | -0.18 |
| Casey | 10.01 | 10.05 | 200 | 50 |

Note that the Increment speed is just the (Position increment /(start time - end time)), where the end time is just the time of next movement for each Participant (Name).

Is there a way to perform such computation?

Thank you

Comment: You can use window functions `lead`/`lag` provided your dbms support it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use self join.

```
CREATE TABLE speed_test(name varchar(10), time int, position int);
mysql> INSERT INTO speed_test VALUES ('Brittany', 1020, -75);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO speed_test VALUES ('Brittany', 1030, 800);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO speed_test VALUES ('Brittany', 1045, 800);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO speed_test VALUES ('Brittany', 1100, 900);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO speed_test VALUES ('Alan', 1015, 400);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO speed_test VALUES ('Alan', 1016, -700);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO speed_test VALUES ('Alan', 1020, 800);

   SELECT t1.name , t2.time as start_time, t1.time as end_time , 
  t1.position, t1.position/(t1.time-t2.time) 
    FROM speed_test t1 
    LEFT JOIN 
    speed_test t2
    ON t2.name=t1.name 
       AND t2.time<t1.time 
       AND t2.time=(SELECT max(time) FROM  speed_test WHERE t1.name=name AND time<t1.time);

+----------+------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+
| name     | start_time | end_time | position | t1.position/(t1.time-t2.time) |
+----------+------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+
| Brittany |       NULL |     1020 |      -75 |                          NULL |
| Brittany |       1020 |     1030 |      800 |                       80.0000 |
| Brittany |       1030 |     1045 |      800 |                       53.3333 |
| Brittany |       1045 |     1100 |      900 |                       16.3636 |
| Alan     |       NULL |     1015 |      400 |                          NULL |
| Alan     |       1015 |     1016 |     -700 |                     -700.0000 |
| Alan     |       1016 |     1020 |      800 |                      200.0000 |
+----------+------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+
```

Difference in speed is because of int vs time in time column.

Comment: You need to convert the time to time format for calculation. For example, if `start_time` is 1045 and `end_time` is 1100, then the difference is 55 mins but not 15 mins. It will cause calculation wrong (900/55 = 16.3636) but the answer should be (900/15=60)

Answer (score 0):

Since your TimeFormat is `HH.mm`, you need to catch hour and minute separately.

If you are using `SQL Server`, try the following:

```
Create table #temp
(
 Name varchar(100), Time numeric(6,2), Position_Increment int
)
INSERT INTO #temp
values
('Brittany',10.20,-75 )
,('Brittany',10.30,800 )
,('Brittany',10.45,800 )
,('Brittany',11.00,900 )
,('Alan',10.15,400 )
,('Alan',10.16,-700)
,('Alan',10.20,800 )
,('Casey',9.50,800 )
,('Casey',10.01,-400)
,('Casey',10.05,200 )



;with cte as 
(
      select Name
            ,Time as EndTime
            ,Position_Increment
            ,Lag(EndTimeHH,1,0) over (partition by Name order by Time ) as StartTimeHH
            ,Lag(EndTimemm,1,0) over (partition by Name order by Time ) as StartTimemm
            ,StartTime
            ,EndTimeHH
            ,EndTimemm
      from
      (
         select *
               ,SUBSTRING(cast(time as varchar),1,CHARINDEX('.',time)-1) as EndTimeHH
               ,SUBSTRING(cast(time as varchar),CHARINDEX('.',time)+1,len(time)) as EndTimemm
               ,Lag(Time,1,0) over (partition by Name order by Time ) as StartTime
         from #temp
      ) as t
)

select Name
      ,CASE WHEN StartTime =0 Then '-' ELSE CAST(StartTime AS varchar) END AS StartTime
      ,EndTime
      ,Position_Increment
      ,CASE WHEN StartTime =0 
            Then '-' 
            ELSE CAST(Position_Increment /ABS(((StartTimeHH*60+StartTimemm) - (EndTimeHH*60+EndTimemm))) AS varchar)
       END AS IncrementSpeed
from cte
order by name
 
Drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pseudo-code explains what to do:

```
select name,
       lag(time) over (partition by name order by time) as start_time,
       time as end_time,
       ( position_increment /
         (time - lag(time) over (partition by name order by time))
       ) as increment_speed
from t;
```

The one caveat is that date/time functions vary significantly be database, so you need to use the appropriate logic to subtract two times.